# Develop and test Python code to connect kafka streams on local machine

Tags: python, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

I am new to Python on local machine. Till now I can code in Azure Databricks. I want to create and deploy libraries which connects to confluent kafka and save data to delta table.
I got confused -
1] Do I need to connect to Databricks Delta from my local machine using python to store the streams to delta
OR
Store the streams to local delta (I am able to create delta table) by setting up like below

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

and deploy the lib into databricks , when it will run it will point to Databricks Delta

I want to use dbfs filestore as well to connect to kafka

```
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test.jks") \
```

I am new to this, Please share the details about How to create streaming application in Python?
and How to deploy to Databricks?

Comment: Databricks offers notebooks for running the code. What issues are you having with it? Also https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Comment: Our requirement is to deploy egg files on databricks. Not to use Notebooks directly

Comment: egg files are just imported as libraries, not runnable scripts, AFAIK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390059/running-python-package-egg-in-azure-databricks-job

Answer (score 0):

To execute the Python code on Databricks without notebooks, you need to configure a [job](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html).  As was mentioned by OneCricketeer, the `egg` is the file format for libraries, you will need to have a Python file that will be the entry point for the job - it will initialize the Spark session, and then will call your libraries.

Job could be configured either (you will also need to upload your libraries):

1. via UI, but it's limited to configuring the notebooks and jars, but not the Python code. But you'll still able to run Python code, using the `spark-submit` option.
2. via [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#create) - with it, you can create a job that executes Python code directly
3. via [command-line](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli.html) (uses REST API under the hood) and you'll need to create JSON yourself, same way as for REST API.
4. via [Databricks Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs) - it also uses REST API, but could be easier to configure everything in one place - upload libraries, upload the file to DBFS, create/modify the job.

On Databricks, Delta is already pre-installed, so you don't need to set options, and specify maven coordinates, and everything else, so your initialization code will be:

```py
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()
```